# How to manage click event and hover effect on touch device?

Tags: css, hover, touch, href

The touch device works both `:hover` or `href="/products.php"` on the first tap. Is there any **CSS** solution for managing menu nav link and its submenu ?

```css
html, body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navigation {
  width: 300px;
}

.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.mainmenu a:focus, .mainmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #C5C5C5;
}

.mainmenu li:focus .submenu, .mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}

.submenu a:focus, .submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/products.php">Products</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="/Tops">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Bottoms">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Footwear">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/LOrPVw

Comment: Generally, you add `:focus` as well as `:hover`, but this doesn't work when your trigger (Products) is also a hyperlink that will respond to clicks

Comment: @AndrewBone Still the result is same :-(

Comment: It's actually the anchor (`<a>`) that will get focus not the list element like this `.mainmenu li a:focus .submenu`

Comment: @AndrewBone still not sure how to fix it ! https://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/LOrPVw

Comment: @AndrewBone The portfolio website http://www.athimannil.com/ works properly unfortunately no idea how it works there.